# Laravel use pagination for simple Query maker

Tags: php, laravel

in this simple `scope` in model i want to create query by user options, unfortunately i get error for `->paginate()` in below code and i cant fix that

**Error:**

```
Call to undefined function App\paginate()
```

**My scope code:**

```
public function scopeDate($query, $start, $finish, $type, $day, $order_type)
{
    $sub_query = $query;
    if (intval($day) == 0) {
        $sub_query
            ->where('created_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d") . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', date("Y-m-d") . ' 24:00:00');
    } else {
        $sub_query
            ->where('created_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start)) . ' 00:00:00')
            ->where('created_at', '<=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($finish)) . ' 24:00:00');
    }

    if ($type != 0) {
        $sub_query->whereType($type);
    }

    $order_type == 0 ? $sub_query->orderBy('id', 'DESC'):$sub_query->orderBy('id', 'ASC') ;

    return $sub_query->paginate(50);
}
```

Comment: May be Laravel doesn't allow calling paginate inside `scopes`, try to do the pagination out of your `scope` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is great, but what if you wanted to paginate results? Unfortunately, you can’t just chain Laravel’s paginate method to the custom static method.You should use

```
public function scopeDate($query, $start, $finish, $type, $day,$order_type)
{
$sub_query = $query;
if (intval($day) == 0) {
    $sub_query
        ->where('created_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d") . ' 00:00:00')
        ->where('created_at', '<=', date("Y-m-d") . ' 24:00:00');
} else {
    $sub_query
        ->where('created_at', '>=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start)) . ' 00:00:00')
        ->where('created_at', '<=', date("Y-m-d", strtotime($finish)) . ' 24:00:00');
}

if ($type != 0) {
    $sub_query->whereType($type);
}

$order_type == 0 ? $sub_query->orderBy('id', 'DESC'):$sub_query->orderBy('id', 'ASC') ;

return $sub_query;
}
```

then

```
Class::date($start, $finish, $type, $day, $order_type)->paginate(50);
```